# Vuetify: How to execute `this.$refs.form.validate()` from a parent component?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to execute `this.$refs.myform.validate()` from a parent component ?

The child is set like this in the parent component

```
<LazyProfileIdentity ref="MyComponentRef" />
```

The form in the child component is set like this:

```
<form ref="MyFormRef" v-model="valid">
...
</form>
```

I tried this:

```
this.$refs.MyComponentRef.$refs.MyFormRef.validate()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
this.$refs.MyComponentRef.$refs.MyFormRef.validate is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the $refs twice. I've added a picture from the relevant part in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html).
Good luck!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTZHw.png)

Comment: I had a typo, I was using `form` instead of `v-form`. I actually need `$refs` twice, accessing `this.$refs.MyFormRef.validate()` called from the parent is undefined.

Comment: Please add the code snippet in the answer to better help the people benefit from it.